# How do I create a Loop using Python that calculates means for each timeseries subsample sequence?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I am trying to create a function that takes a time-series and several splits as arguments. If the split =3, I would expect the function to split the time-series data into thirds and calculate an average for each split.
 The code I created below calculates the mean accumulatively.
Here is the sample data:

```
data = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9])
```

Here is the function I created:

```
def multi_mean(ts, n_splits = 3):
    ts_ranges = []
    mn_range = []
    for i in range(1,n_splits+1):
        result = int(round(len(ts)/(i),0))
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            result2 = ts[:result*j].mean()
            mn_range.append(result2)         
    return mn_range
```

The function on the fake data provides the following list of results:

```
rs1 = multi_mean(data,2)
[5.4,3.0,5.4]
```

The first number is for a split of i =1, which is the entire sample.
The second number is the first average for i = 2, which is the average of the first 5 numbers.
The second number for i =2, averages all numbers.
I cannot figure out how to construct the slice in the loop so that I can get the desired result.
I want the following desired result:

```
[5.4,3.0,7.8]
```

Last, I would ideally like to output each round i into a separate list object.

Comment: Why are you getting 3 numbers in your answer when n_splits=2?

Comment: I want a sequence of splits. So split = 2 is actually two rounds of splits. The first round is the whole sample. The second round splits the data into halves.

Comment: And what are you going to do with the remainder if/when it's not wholly divisible, so like 10/3

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on what you're trying to do? Is there any reason why you're using Pandas over, say, NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical part is that you forgot to specify the *start* of each slice.
BTW, you don't need to do this as a PANDAS series; a simple list will do

Change the central line to have a start to the slice:

```
    result2 = sum(ts[result*(j-1):result*j]) / result
```

Output:

```
[5.4, 3.0, 7.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Prune successfully fixed your code, but I couldn't resist sharing a different solution. All hail NumPy!

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools as itt

arr_1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9])


def split_means(arr, num_splits):
    means_gen = ((curr_slice.mean() for curr_slice in np.array_split(arr, i)) for i in range(1, num_splits + 1))
    means_iter = itt.chain.from_iterable(means_gen)
    return list(means_iter)


print(split_means(arr_1, 2))
```

Comment: Prune solved the problem, but I thank you for this solution also as I am trying to learn functional programming as well